# Cannot override CSS

Tags: css, overriding

I am trying to change the color of the text in my header right widget when I scroll down the page. I want the text to change from white to orange when I scroll down.

Here is the CSS I tried adding:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 800px) {
.header-scroll .site-header {
    color: #FF6600 !important;
}
}
.header-right {
    color: #fff;
}
```

!important; is not overriding the white color I assigned to the header right text.

Here is my website: https://asdeathdouspart.com/

Any ideas or help? Thank you!

Comment: please can you show your html structure too - also are you testing in a browser wider than 800px?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website OR off-site example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: Isn't there any other classes that change text-color to white behind those? Or when linking the CSS page?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are targeting the parent, not the child, try this:

```
.header-right {
 color:  #FF6600 !important; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your media query. You close the brace too early

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 800px) {
        .header-scroll .site-header {
            color: #FF6600 !important;
         }

         .header-right {
             color: #fff;
         }

}
```